# Static member data of template class with two parameters

Tags: c++, templates

http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/templates/static_members.html makes it clear what I need to do - if the template has a single parameter.

What if it had two?

```
template <typename T, typename T2> class X {
  public:
     static int st_;
 };
```

How would I template the static memebr data?

```
template <typename T, typename T2> int, int X<T, T2>::st_;
```

or

```
template <typename T, typename T2> int int X<T, T2>::st_;
```

or what?

I *think* that my problem is knowinng what to do with the two real types (both int here).

After templating, how do I declare my static member variable?

Comment: Where did you get that weird idea about two types? Your variable has type `int`. Why are you insisting on repeating it twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template <typename T, typename T2>
int X<T, T2>::st_;
```

You don't need two `int`-s. The `int` is the just type of `st_`.

Comment: D'oh!!   

Thanks. Can you tell me how I initialize the static member var?  

`int X<int, int>::st_= 0;` doesn't seem to be correct.

Aha!!  http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TooFewTemplateParameterLists   shows that *with g++*, I need  
`template <> int X<int, int>::st_= 0;`  
just in case anyone is wondering